# From where to learn finite element method?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, reference-request

Can anyone reccomend me a book or site for learning finite element method with mathematica, besides wolfram language official site,
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html.
A saw that there is a lot of material for matlab but very few for mathematica.

Comment: Are you looking to understand the finite element method (so that in principle you could implement it yourself), or just learn how to solve PDE using Mathematica's FEM tools, without fully understanding the method?

Comment: I am familiar with FEM analysis. I am good with working with abaqus, I would like to learn more about FEM programming in mathematica. But like I said, it seams there are no books. Only online documentation.

Comment: What do you find lacking in the tutorial you linked?

Comment: Nothing specific. I was just wondering if there was any book or video tutorials for this topic, because I preffer them more. I saw a lot of books covering matlab and FEM analysis, and I was wondering if there are any books of that kind for mathematica, because it preffer to learn from book where things are more written and explained in more structured way.

Comment: Do you find that this tutorial is not structured? It has sections and subsections, and presents the topic in a coherent manner. I do not see the difference from a book, other than that it is not printed on paper (but you *can* print the notebooks).  If you have concrete suggestions for improvement, perhaps you can mention them.

Comment: Like I sad, I prefer to learn from book instead of looking at computer screen for long time, I didn't say it isn't structured, just that the books is better in my opinion. I will try with online documentation, than. Thank you for this conversation Szabolcs :)!

Comment: Just to be clear, I do not think the question is invalid. I was just wondering about your motivation.

Answer (score 1):

May be this book would be useful:

[Fundamental Finite Element Analysis and Applications: with Mathematica and Matlab Computations written by M.Asghar Bhatti](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471648086)

Comment: Is it really from 2005? The FEM functionality became an official part of Mma only in 2014.  There was some undocumented mesh functionality prior to that, but I don't know much about it (when it became available, what it did).  I doubt a 2005 book will help someone learn how to use the new (since 2014) FEM functions, although it might help with general FEM knowledge. Can you add some description of what you found useful?